# Mysql: how to select groups having certain values?

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by, having

Say there is such table:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM tags;
+---------+--------+
| post_id | tag_id |
+---------+--------+
|       1 |      2 |
|       1 |      3 |
|       1 |      1 |
|       2 |      1 |
|       2 |      2 |
+---------+--------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Field names are pretty self-explanatory. I want to select `post_id`s that have both 1 and 3 `tag_id`s, so in this example it's only `1`. I thought of something like 
`SELECT post_id FROM tags GROUP BY post_id HAVING ...` After having I'd like to list `tag_id`s that are present in this group. How do I do that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If there aren't any unique constraints try:

```
SELECT post_id 
FROM tags 
WHERE tag_id = 1 OR tag_id = 3 
GROUP BY post_id 
HAVING count(DISTINCT tag_id) = 2;
```

Or use this `HAVING` clause, if trying to detect only two `tag_id` values:

```
HAVING MIN(tag_id) <> MAX(tag_id)
```

If post_id and tag_id both have an unique constraint, this should work too:

```
SELECT post_id 
FROM tags 
WHERE tag_id = 1 OR tag_id = 3 
GROUP BY post_id 
HAVING count(*) = 2;
```

Comment: Thanks, I decided to go with `SELECT post_id FROM tags WHERE tag_id IN (1,3) GROUP BY post_id HAVING COUNT(1) = 2;`, which scales well and is the closest to your solution

Answer (score 3):

You could try a self join (N tag_id -> N join) but probably it's not fast

```
SELECT t1.post_id 
FROM tags t1 INNER JOIN tags t2 ON t1.post_id = t2.post_id 
WHERE t1.tag_id = 1 AND t2.tag_id = 3
```

Comment: Doesn't really scale for an arbitrary amount of tags though.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT post_id
  FROM ( SELECT post_id,
                count(tag_id) AS counter
           FROM tags
          WHERE tag_id IN (1,3)
          GROUP BY post_id
       )
 WHERE counter = 2
```

Use GROUP_CONCAT() for the second part of your question

```
SELECT post_id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(tag_id ORDER BY tag_id ASC SEPARATOR ',')
  FROM tags
```

Answer (score 1):

I've made some assumptions about your other tables. (i.e. that you have a table for posts that I have called `posts` and one with tag_id as the PK which I have called `tag_table` to avoid a nameclash with the posts/tags table that I can see you already call `tags`)

You want posts where there does not exist a tag in the list {1,3} for which there does not exist a matching record with the corresponding post_id/tag_id so you can use a double NOT EXISTS construct as below.

```
SELECT post_id
FROM posts p
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT * FROM tag_table tt
    WHERE tag_id IN (1,3)
    AND NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT * FROM tags t
        WHERE t.tag_id = tt.tag_id  and
        p.post_id = t.post_id)        
    )
```

Another alternative approach is to use Group By and Count. [A review of approaches to this problem is here](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/).

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
SELECT * 
FROM tags 
WHERE post_id in 
  (SELECT post_id AS pid 
   FROM tags 
   WHERE 1 IN (SELECT tag_id FROM tags WHERE post_id = pid) 
   AND 3 IN (SELECT tag_id FROM tags WHERE post_id = pid)
  );
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

WHERE version of @Keeper's solution

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.post_id 
FROM tags t1, tags t2
WHERE 
  t1.post_id = t2.post_id  AND 
  t1.tag_id = 1 AND t2.tag_id = 3
```

Comment: Don't think that the second clause of your OR is useful.